# Tuple inference via literal typing (i.e brute force typing)

Tags: typescript

This seems so obvious and simple, but I can't get it to work. Would love to get everybody's perspective to see if you can find what am I missing.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArAggLhgbwGYhK6ATgJZgDmAvjALyYw54Dk8AhgQzOQNwBQoksCRACF02XPijEylGhjriYTVgy7duWMAAoA2txgxtg5ABoYmgG7MANgEpqAPkzkAuse4B6dzAB6v7zCgATwAHAFMYIggYUAICULAoADo9fVT9Tx9fGFCADzDgWCCwgJAYeHCxPEISCjMIZgBbcOYo4JAIIigicBgARhtTeABXWFIQWAADIbAAazAQAHcwCZTDJCFTC2s7KkcMFzd0rwBJIWOAEW5nGx5uABNQ4CtWcKxpgu6wOjAAHhTkHKHGBCQH-bI5KDxO5ReKSQIAfQAKj8AfYgUJwZCwNDsgkCAjkSC0dx7JpWKQIOhtCZgQB+a7ocwgIh3W5FcKw-FIn4ADUcNG0PM2lis6B5O0cTJZzh4QA)

```
const objA: {foo:string} = { foo:'bar' };
const objB: {foo:string} = { foo: 'bar'};

fn([
  [objA, (val) => {}],
// ^^^^ type is corrent.
        // ^^^ expect type to be {foo:string} (same as position 1), but got `unknown`
  [objB, (val) => {}],
  // IBID
]);

declare function fn<
  Ax,
  Bx,
  A extends entry_T<Ax>,
  B extends entry_T<Bx>,
>(args: [A, B?]): void;

type entry_T<X> = [X, (val: X) => void];
```

Comment: I do not see `unknown` but the correct type being inferred.

Comment: Strange... are you using v4.6.2? Just to double check, [is this not what you're seeing?](https://imgur.com/a/ntE91ok)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be another case of type inference not working through multiple levels of generics. Pretty sure I have seen issues about that on Github, but they are hard to find again.

If it is not too much of a hassle, you could just drop the extra layer that wraps the tuple:

```
declare function fn<A, B>(args: [[A, Fun<A>], [B, Fun<B>]?]): void;
type Fun<X> = (val: X) => void;
```

Comment: Oh wow, that is... not intuitive at all... I can't believe what is essentially the same thing works in one form but not another. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user1543574 Glad that works for you. Would be nice to have a bug tracking issue to point too, unfortunately there currently are over 5000 open issues to look through 